# How do I print only non repeated elements in a list in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I've an array `arr = [4, 8, 2, 8, 9]`.

I want to print the elements that doesn't repeat.

i.e. 4, 2, 9

but my code is giving list index out of range even though the same logic is working in Java but not in my Python code. Here is my code:

```
def odd_occurring_num(arr):
    count = 0
    size = len(arr)
    
    for i in arr:
        for j in arr:
            if (arr[i] == arr[j] and i != j):
                break
        if (j == size):
            count += 1
    return count
    
# driver Code
arr = [4, 8, 2, 8, 9]
print(odd_occurring_num(arr))
```

Comment: Here i and j is not an index rather they are the element of array

Comment: You go over the _elements_ of the list (i.e. `i` will take on the _value_ of each element of the list in turn) - but you use is as if you iterated over _indexes_ into your lists. See dupe to so solve what you want to do. As to why it works in Java but not Python: _Python ain't no Java_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't even need to import modules, Python has it all built in

```
arr = [4, 8, 2, 8, 9]
def odd_occurring_num(arr):
    return [i for i in arr if arr.count(i) < 2]

print(odd_occurring_num(arr))
```

what you did:

```
for i in arr:
    arr[i] = ...
```

will actually iterate through the items of array, so you are getting `arr[4]` which is `9`, then `arr[8]` which is not defined as you list is only 5 elements.
What you can do is:

```
for i, elem in enumerate(arr):
   arr[i] = ...
```

which will iterate over the index `i` and the elements itself

Comment: I understood and it worked. Thank you, I new to python but this is awesome just few lines code done same thing that I wrote many lines in java. Can you please tell what is this [i for i in arr if arr.count(i) < 2]. I have no idea of such type loop. why to write this inside square bracket? Please don't mind just tell me a bit so I can google about it Thanks again.

Comment: its a list comprehension: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate it

Comment: @AlexanderRiedel Is this the fastest way to do it? Also, is it memory efficient? I'm working on a project where I have to try to save every byte and every second possible. Could you suggest any updated option? Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from collections import Counter                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

c = Counter([4, 8, 2, 8, 9])    
[i for i,j in c.items() if j==1]
```

This will returns:

```
[4, 2, 9]
```

Also if you take a look at `c` you can see:

```
Counter({4: 1, 8: 2, 2: 1, 9: 1})
```